# Auto Increment ID in SharePoint 2016 based on old ID from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to migrate a list in sharepoint, but there are gaps in the old id system. So I am trying to manually create an ID field that looks to see if there is an old ID and if so displays that, but if not creates one based on the last entered +1. Something similar to =IF([@[ID]=TRUE],[ID],MAX([ID]+1) but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using =IF([@[ID]=TRUE],[ID],MAX(VALUE[ID])+1)